# How to search events for a value from new eval fieldname in Splunk?

Tags: search, eval, encode, splunk

I need to search for events that contains specific value generated from a new field name. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
index=app sourcetype=source 
| eval uri_t = "uri:type:subtype:123-5678:DATA_REFERENCE:DATA1:999:123-5678:DATA2:DATA_REFERENCE2:123456" 
| eval uri2=replace(uri_t, "\:", "%3A") 
| search uri2
```

Basically, I'm encoding part of a url using replace and eval function into field name uri2, then i need to search specifically in the result of the encoded value. But it seems using search, will search for "uri2" instead of the entire encoded string.

Note, I had to use replace to encode part of the url because it seems there is no encode function in splunk.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've learned, the `search` command searches entire events.  To find text within a field, use one of these commands.

```
| where match(uri2, "<regex>")

| regex uri2="<regex>"
```

Both of them will filter out events that do not match the given regular expression.

If you want to find a substring within the field without filtering events, then use the `rex` command.

```
| rex field=uri2 "<regex>"
```

Note that `rex` must contain a named capture group.  The group name will become  field into which `rex` will put the matching text.

Comment: Actually, and my mistake when I wrote the question, i'm looking for events that contains the decoded value.

Comment: I thought that Splunk only has urldecode but not urlencode one

Comment: I meant to say that Splunk has a `urldecode` function.  Use it to decode the URL then do the string matching/extraction.

Comment: So rex/match command will return events containing that string?